# Android addrule(RelativeLayout.BELOW) does not render correctly

Tags: android, android-layout

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, checkBox.getId());

    LinearLayout li = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_layout);
    EditText ed = new EditText(RegisterActivity.this);
    ed.setLayoutParams(params);

    li.addView(ed);
}
```

this is my code in activity file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/checkbox_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/hsc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
        android:text="HSC"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/ielts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
        android:text="IELTS"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/toefl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
        android:text="TOEFL"
        android:textSize="15sp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

this is my xml layout file

I just want to add Edittext right below the "checked" checkbox dynamically but when i run this code, the Edittext is added at the bottom of the Linearlayout...

How can i add right below the checkbox??

Comment: oh cool i got it umm any solution or workaround?

Answer (score 0):

It happens because You trying to setup `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` and put `View` to the `LinearLayout`. LinearLayout ignores the specific fields of `RelativeLayout`.

If You want to add View after checkbox You need to know position of checkbox and place new View after that using [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View,%20int)) method.

Comment: ok i got it i will try to work around on your solution thanks